# UWP share internal and SD-card storage

Tags: c#, storage, win-universal-app, sd-card

I want to know, if it is possible to have shared internal and external (SD-card) access in a mobile c# UWP App. I know, that one can decide, whether to install new Apps internally or on SD-card via *Settings* -> *System* -> *Storage*.

The problem: I have a SQLite database, that I would like to run on internal NAND storage at all costs (for obvious performance reasons) and then I have a lot of images, that don't necessarily need to be on the internal NAND, but can be "outsourced" to the SD-card (so they don't clutter up valuable space especially on budget phones).

The MS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card) suggests, that one can use the external SD-card like a drive. That solution however is not suitable to me, because it can only open file-types specified in the app-declarations and also these files would be visible to everyone and are not in a hidden app-container, like apps are.

Is there a solution or workaround for my issue?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't have your isolated storage be split between both internal and external storage. Have you actually run into issues when your SQLite DB resides on the SD-card or is it mainly an assumption that it would cause perceivable performance issues?

Comment: It's an assumption. Because I do not load the whole DB into memory in the beginning, I do have a SQLite connection, that I call every time I need data out of it. Depending on what the user is doing, this can be quite often.